# Create permissions based on model field names in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create permissions, so that every user is able to see the articles of specific authors. Example permissions are `Can view author1`, `Can view author2` etc. and `Can view all`. In the article class I tried creating the permissions as follow:

```
class Article(models.Model)
    #some not important stuff
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_%s' % Author.name, 'Can view %s' % Author.name),
            ('view_all', 'Can view all'),
        )
```

This did not work and from what I know the permissions are stored in the database, so is it even possible to create the permissions this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better design solution would be:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    ...
    my_allowed_viewers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='views_allowed', reverse=False)
```

and then make the permission like

```
class IsAuthorizedReader(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        author_id = request.user.id
        author_to_view_id = request.data.get('author_to_view_id')
        if author_to_view_id is not None:
            return Authors.objects.get(pk=author_to_view_id).my_allowed_viewers.filter(author_id).exists()
        return False
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve, I want to create the permissions in the meta depending on the author's names.